# How can I implement mobile responsive behavior of this form using BootStrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a web application using BootStrap and I have the following problem. Into a view (a modal) I have defined this form:

```
  <form [formGroup]="newPatientForm" id="addPatientForm" (ngSubmit)=saveNewPatient()>
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
              <p>Nome</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
                <input id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" type="text" pInputText />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Cognome</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
              <input id="surname" formControlName="surname" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Data di nascita</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10" [ngClass]="{'ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched': isEmptyDate}">
            <p-calendar [ngClass]="{'invalid-date': isValidDate}"
                        id="birthDate" 
                        [(ngModel)]="birthDateNg"
                        inputId="birthDate"
                        formControlName="birthDate"
                        >
            </p-calendar>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Luogo di nascita</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
              <input id="placeOfBirth" formControlName="placeOfBirth" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Codice fiscale</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
              <input id="socialSecurityCode" formControlName="socialSecurityCode" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>E-mail</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
              <input id="personalEmail" formControlName="personalEmail" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Telefono</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
              <input id="personalPhone" formControlName="personalPhone" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-2">
            <p>Professione</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
              <input id="occupation" formControlName="occupation" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <p-footer>
          <span class="p-buttonset">
            <button pButton 
                    type="submit"
                    label="Save" 
                    icon="pi pi-check"
                    [disabled]="!newPatientForm.valid">
            </button>
            <button pButton type="button" label="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" (click)="closeDialog()"></button>
        </span>
        </p-footer>
               
  </form>
```

Rendering it in desktop mode it have no problem, it is rendered in the expected way:

[image]

But rendering in mobile mode it is pretty ugly and absolutly not responsive:

[image]

How can I adapt it in order to be responsive ad good looking on mobile? Bootstrap provide some extra classes for the column width in mobile visualization or something like it?

Comment: Can you add this in JSFiddle so that I can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

rows should always be in containers.

```
<form [formGroup]="newPatientForm" id="addPatientForm" (ngSubmit)=saveNewPatient()>
    <div class="container">
        //other codes you wrote
    </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap have separate classes for mobile and large screen so you have to add some more classes to fix issue on mobile.

**col-12:** it will give full width on mobile screen & large screen

**col-md-*:** it will adjust size on large screens

Try the following code to fix your issue......

```
 <form [formGroup]="newPatientForm" id="addPatientForm" (ngSubmit)=saveNewPatient()>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
              <p>Nome</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                <input id="firstName" formControlName="firstName" type="text" pInputText />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <p>Cognome</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
              <input id="surname" formControlName="surname" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <p>Data di nascita</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10" [ngClass]="{'ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched': isEmptyDate}">
            <p-calendar [ngClass]="{'invalid-date': isValidDate}"
                        id="birthDate" 
                        [(ngModel)]="birthDateNg"
                        inputId="birthDate"
                        formControlName="birthDate"
                        >
            </p-calendar>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <p>Luogo di nascita</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
              <input id="placeOfBirth" formControlName="placeOfBirth" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <p>Codice fiscale</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
              <input id="socialSecurityCode" formControlName="socialSecurityCode" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <p>E-mail</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
              <input id="personalEmail" formControlName="personalEmail" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <p>Telefono</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
              <input id="personalPhone" formControlName="personalPhone" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <p>Professione</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
              <input id="occupation" formControlName="occupation" type="text" pInputText />
          </div>
        </div>

        <p-footer>
          <span class="p-buttonset">
            <button pButton 
                    type="submit"
                    label="Save" 
                    icon="pi pi-check"
                    [disabled]="!newPatientForm.valid">
            </button>
            <button pButton type="button" label="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" (click)="closeDialog()"></button>
        </span>
        </p-footer>
</div>
               
  </form>
```

Comment: I still have the same issue...mnaybe use a modal is not the best thing to do to achieve mobile responsivness?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle so that I can fix your issue there?
which bootstrap version R u using?